# Invoke and BeginInvoke won't run true async

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

Ok, there are some solutions to fixing multithreading Windows Forms.  Mine is like that...only there is a 1-second delay:

```
private delegate void StupidDumb();
private void StupidFreakingDumb()
{
    RespondLbl.BeginInvoke(new StupidDumb(() => RespondLbl.Text = "Responding: Loading..."));
    // Then refresh
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        RespondLbl.BeginInvoke(new StupidDumb(() => RespondLbl.Text = $"Responding: {SerialCommunication.Responding}"));
        // The 'SerialCommunication.Responding' property takes up to one second to retrieve information, which is the same amount of time the form is not responding.
    }).Start();
}
private void RefreshBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(StupidFreakingDumb));
}
```

I put it in the code but I'll put it here too:

"The 'SerialCommunication.Responding' property takes up to one second to retrieve information, which is the same amount of time the form is not responding."

In the 'RefreshBtn_Click' method, I have tried BeginInvoke, Invoke, and new Thread instances.

The closest I've gotten was the new Thread method and did update the form showing 'Responding: Loading...' but then freezing for 1 whole second until SerialCommunication.Responding returns a value.

EDIT (I have a bad habit of posting something then finding a solution shortly after):

Changed

```
RespondLbl.BeginInvoke(new StupidDumb(() => RespondLbl.Text = $"Responding: {SerialCommunication.Responding}"));
```

to

```
string poop = SerialCommunication.Responding.ToString();
RespondLbl.BeginInvoke(new StupidDumb(() => RespondLbl.Text = $"Responding: {poop}"));
```

That fixed it.  Just make sure that the long process (SerialCommunication.Responding, for example) is not part of the Invoke/BeginInvoke method.  Put it in a separate object then, once that object has that value, trigger the Invoke/BeginInvoke (minor differences, tried both, can't even tell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just put the answer down here:

I changed

```
RespondLbl.BeginInvoke(new StupidDumb(() => RespondLbl.Text = $"Responding: {SerialCommunication.Responding}"));
```

to

```
string poop = SerialCommunication.Responding.ToString();
RespondLbl.BeginInvoke(new StupidDumb(() => RespondLbl.Text = $"Responding: {poop}"));
```

Just make sure that the long process (SerialCommunication.Responding, in my case) is not part of the Invoke/BeginInvoke method. Assign it to a separate object then, once that object has that value, trigger the Invoke/BeginInvoke (minor differences, tried both, can't even tell)